# Using ASP.NET MVC 2 credentials to log into other services

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Here is my scenario -

1/ I have an ASP.NET MVC application running on my server, it uses Windows Authentication.

2/ There is different web application (written in Java) somewhere else that also uses Windows Authentication.

In the Controller of my MVC application I need to grab some information from this other Web app. How can I connect to the "foreign" application using the credentials of the user that is accessing my Controller?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I think this thread can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405612/impersonation-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 1):

Impersonation doesn't leave the ASPNET process. This means that you cannot delegate the credentials and access a remote resource using them. You could either swap back to Forms authentication which uses cookies or you will need [Kerberos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998351.aspx#paght000023%5Fimpersonatingbyusingwindowsidentity).