# MVC3 Intranet Application and Shared Folders/Drives on a Windows Domain

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, intranet

I am trying to find a solution where users have access to shared drives on the network/windows domain. I created a basic MVC3 Intranet application which recognized my domain username and displays it in the browser out of the box.

the question is how hard is it to implement a web based file share GUI using the MVC3 Intranet App where users are authenticated on the network or through their integrated windows authentication when they log in to their stations?

The idea is to avoid that the users have to manually map shared drive across the network and have a user friendly GUI to manage/share their files.

Thanks

Comment: Well if you create a file share on one of the servers you can access it by \\servername\fileshare.  With that in mind you could create a UI by targeting the directory with you Mvc app.

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent the wheel when many such services already exist for file sharing?
http://www.box.com/
etc etc

The security is possible, you'll need to enable delegation and cross your fingers.

[Impersonation in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405612/impersonation-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: well its not up to me, the reason for not using something like box is the users are to authenticate using their Active Directory credentials/access levels. thanks for your input; i will diff give it a try.