# Impersonation and Delegation within a MVC 3 application on IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5, impersonation, delegation

Given the follow scenario:

- Windows 2008 R2 x64 web server with IIS 7.5, **Server 1**
- Windows 2003 R2 x64 file server, **Server 2**
- MVC 3 application with Windows authentication and impersonation
  (authenticated user)
- Configured **Server 1** as `'Trusted computer for delegation'` in Active
  directory
- Internet Explorer 8

Within the application the user has the possibility to upload a file. This uploaded file has to be saved on **Server 2**. In the code we create the UNC path to this **Server 2** and save it there.

```
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
  var savedDirectory = "\\Path\To\Server2";

  if (Directory.Exists(savedDirectory))
  {
    file.SaveAs(savedFileName);
  }
  else
  {
    Directory.CreateDirectory(savedDirectory);
    file.SaveAs(savedFileName);
  }

  return RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller", new { id = 1 });
}
```

We installed the application on **Server 1** and test it locally on **Server 1**, everything went fine. Files are uploaded to **Server 2** no issues there.

When we test the same scenario from a client desktop we get an error saying that there is not enough permissions to save the file on **Server 2**.

A wireshark session shows us **Server 1** did not impersonate, because the authenticated user on **Server 2** was empty/anonymous.

### Impersonation as Specific User instead of Authenticated User

We did not get the impersonation working so we created a service account and configured the application to impersonate with this `Specific User` instead of the `Authenticated User`. The service account is a domain account and has permissions on the folder on **Server 2**.

When we try to upload, the service account has no permissions on the local folder where we upload the file from.

### Delegation

We learned, via [Impersonation in asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405612/impersonation-in-asp-net-mvc/1405666#1405666), that we need to trust **Server 1** for delegation.

After we trusted **Server 1** for delegation: still no permissions to save the file on **Server 2**. We tried this both with impersonation as `Authenticated User` en `Specific user`

1. Impersonation as `Authenticated User` with delegation not working: not enough permissions on **Server 2**
2. Impersonation as `Specific User` not working: not enough permissions on the **Local folder**

Do we miss something here? Do we need extra steps for delegation?

Comment: Delegation only works with Kerberos, not Windows Integrated (NTLM.) Are you using Kerberos? If you're testing against localhost, be careful: kerberos will not work against the loopback.

Comment: Tnx for your comment, I do not have the logs here, but I think it's kerberos. I'm aware of the localhost issue, cost me also a lot of time once ;)

Comment: The reason I say is because if it's not Kerberos, or is falling back to NTLM then guest/anonymous is the symptom for the double-hop failure issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We fixed this problem by:

1. Configuring delegation on the domain for Server 1
2. And adding `Kerberos provider` to the Application within IIS (right click on Windows Authentication)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error today and here are the steps I did to fix the problem:

1. Make sure that ASP.NET Impersonation is enabled for your site. Go to your site in IIS Manager and under features double click on Authentication then enable ASP.NET Impersonation
2. Use Integrated mode for your app pool
3. Edit your application's web.config file to specify the settings below:

   ```
   <system.webServer>
     <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" /> 
   </system.webServer>
   ```