# ASP.NET MVC 5.0 Impersonate Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tfs, asp.net-mvc-5, impersonation

I have an MVC application that will be running on an IIS 7.5 Server in an application pool running under a service account.

In my application I make a connection to a TFS server, this connection needs to be made by the service account.

My application enforces windows authentication, this is so I can gather usage data about which users use the application. I do this through a custom Action Filter in MVC to collect the username like this:   **HttpContext.User.Identity.Name**

How is it possible for me to impersonate the service account, yet be able to keep the windows username of the original user? I can successfully connect to my TFS server if I use anonymous authentication, while running the application pool under the service account.

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405612/impersonation-in-asp-net-mvc) help?

Comment: Yes, that is perfect! thanks stuartd!