# C# can we use windows login to connect sqlserver database?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Recently i have developped a local backend accessing some data on SQLserver for webdevelopment. So i use the connection string with the parameter "integrated security true".
It works fine until i put my backend in server, the server doesnt recognize the username. I checked the errors. My Backend use the server windows login.
My question: does it exist a way to use the client windows login to connect the database and not the server login? (for example change the connection string ?)
Kind Regards.
Thanks in advance.
PS: Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: The answer to your question is obviously yes - you already connected using your Windows account. Your *actual* question is why did the server reject your account? Is your account allowed to connect to that server to begin with? Are you using a domain account? You can't connect to a server if your account has no permission to connect

Comment: `to use the client windows login to connect the database and not the server login` there's no client and server login. In a Windows domain, one account is used and recognized on all machines. If you don't have a domain account - get a domain account

Comment: [How to delegate windows authentication when running on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47100543/15498)

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answer. I will study the solution about impersonation and delegation. If I get either good or bad news. I will let you know. Have nice day everyone.

Answer (score 0):

We can use windows account to connect to SQL server, suggest you share us the error message that you got when your connection failed. It will help us to analysis the issue. Or you can get the SQL server error message from error log. Refer to [Viewing the SQL Server Error Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/viewing-the-sql-server-error-log?view=sql-server-ver15).